# nested tag such as {% include "{% static 'some.html' %}" %}

Tags: django, static, include

> {% load staticfiles %}
>   {% include "{% static 'some.js' %}" %}

Having trouble making it work.
What's the proper syntax here?

Edit.
I'm trying to include a *.js file here actually.
Does it make more sense now?

Comment: Why not just use `{% include "some.html" %}` ?

Comment: I don't understand what you would expect this to do. The `{% static %}` tag is for, well, static files, and returns a full URL to the file. Why would you want to include an HTML file by its full external URL?

Comment: I've edited the question: from *.html -> *.js Does it make more sense now?

Answer (score 3):

How about just:

```
{% include "some.html" %}
```

or:

```
{% include "myapp/some.html" %}
```

?

In any case, you can't nest tags like that.

Comment: Unfortunately? That's really awful syntax